# Calculate Gravity using Angular Acceleeration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, acceleration

The project I have been assigned is completely open-ended. It simply says

> "determine the value of **g** using angular acceleration (ie: swirling mass).

What would be the most accurate way to achieve this? Would I simply use an angular acceleration formula and back-solve for g? Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you tell us what your first ideas are ?

Comment: Should you "calculate gravity" or show how to determine $g$ experimentally?

Answer (score 1):

If you are supposed to find a way to determine $g$ experimentally, the easiest way is to observe a simple pendulum whose angular oscillation period $T$ for small angles $\theta$  is given by $$T≈2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}$$ If you know the length $L$ of the pendulum, you can determine $g$ from $T$.

Answer (score 0):

g is a linear acceleration.  You must somehow couple linear and angular acceleration.  The first thing that comes to mind is a wheel with a string around the rim attached to a mass.  If the moment of inertia of the wheel is high and the mass is low, the angular acceleration can be calculated by measuring the time of one rotation of the wheel with a stopwatch (or the timing app on an iPhone).  This is a starting point.  The design is up to you.